# Secure Wordpress RSS Feed

Tags: wordpress

I've been looking everywhere for a possibility to protect Wordpress RSS Feed with a (login and) password. There are some solutions, but nothing seems to be working on modern WordPress Core.

The problem is there are some scrapers and aggregator apps stealing our posts, but we also have an own app which works with the default RSS Feed (URL/feed/). Unfortunately every user access our feed from his own IP, so there is no possibility to restrict access to a know IP address only. We would like to have access only with our app (Apple App only), others should get an error page or better a message that they should download our app.

What do you suggest?

Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: Thanks. We are not interested in other feed readers than our own app. He's displaying our posts and his app is blocking Google Ads etc., so it's a disadvantage for us. The feed should only be reachable for our app.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable feed and use WP Rest API and even if he gains access to rest api, use a plugin to secure rest api with a secret key, that will be required for valid connection with your server